# Why is vfork() intended to be used when the child process calls exec() or exit() immediately after creation?

Tags: linux, process, exec, exit, vfork

Operating System Concepts and APUE say

> With vfork(), the parent process
>   is suspended, and the child process uses the address space of the parent.
>   Because vfork() does not use copy-on-write, if the child process changes
>   any pages of the parent’s address space, the altered pages will be visible to the
>   parent once it resumes. Therefore, **vfork() must be used with caution to ensure
>   that the child process does not modify the address space of the parent.**
>
> **vfork()
>   is intended to be used when the child process calls exec() or exit() immediately after
>   creation.**

How shall I understand the last sentence?

When a child process created by `vfork()` calls `exec()`, doesn't `exec()` modify the address space of the parent process, by loading the new program?

When a child process created by `vfork()` calls `exit()`, does  `exit()` not modify the address space of the parent process when terminating the child?

I have preference to Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> When a child process created by `vfork()` calls `exec()`, doesn't `exec()` modify the address space of the parent process, by loading the new program?

No, `exec()` provides a new address space for the new program; it doesn’t modify the parent address space. See for example [the discussion of the `exec` functions in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html), and [the Linux `execve()` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

> When a child process created by vfork() calls exit(), does exit() not modify the address space of the parent process when terminating the child?

Plain `exit()` might – it runs exit hooks installed by the running program (including its libraries). `vfork()` is more restrictive; thus, on Linux, [it mandates](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) the use of [`_exit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) which *doesn’t* call the C library’s clean-up functions.

`vfork()` turned out to be quite difficult to get right; it’s been removed in current versions of the POSIX standard, and [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) should be used instead.

However, unless you *really* know what you’re doing, you should **not** use either `vfork()` or `posix_spawn()`; stick to good old `fork()` and `exec()`.

The Linux manpage linked above provides more context:

> However, in the bad old days a `fork(2)`
>          would require making a complete copy of the caller's data space,
>          often needlessly, since usually immediately afterward an `exec(3)` is
>          done.  Thus, for greater efficiency, BSD introduced the `vfork()`
>          system call, which did not fully copy the address space of the parent
>          process, but borrowed the parent's memory and thread of control until
>          a call to `execve(2)` or an exit occurred.  The parent process was
>          suspended while the child was using its resources.  The use of
>          `vfork()` was tricky: for example, not modifying data in the parent
>          process depended on knowing which variables were held in a register.

Comment: Thanks. "exec() provides a new address space for the new program;"  Is the normal behavior of exec() to load a program into the address space of the process? I didn't find in the two links where it creates a new address space either normally or particularly for vfork().

Comment: It’s not spelled out in as many words (it’s really an implementation detail) — but “This causes
       the program that is currently being run by the calling process to be
       replaced with a new program, with newly initialized stack, heap, and
       (initialized and uninitialized) data segments.” means that the new process is separate from its parent.

Comment: Does the quote mean that execve() run by a vforked child doesn't modify the address space of the parent process, and when the parent resumes running, the parent can continue to use the original stack, heap, and  (initialized and uninitialized) data segments?

Comment: See my answer: `exec*()` does not modify the address space, it rather creates a new one.

Comment: @Tim that’s right, `execve()`doesn’t modify the parent’s address space, and when the parent resumes, it continues unmodified (assuming the child obeyed the contract).

Comment: What's funny is vfork() is winning against just about everything else now. It's ridiculously faster than fork() when you have a gigabyte of writable memory.

Comment: Please don't tell people to use `posix_spawn`.  It is significantly harder to write correct code using `posix_spawn` than with plain old `fork`, and if you try, you may run into the brick wall of there not being a file action or attribute that does the thing you need done in between `fork` and `exec`.  And it is not guaranteed to have vfork-like efficiency, so it doesn't even solve the problem people want it to solve.

Comment: [What happens to the old stack, heap, and (initialized and uninitialized) data segments after execve() call?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475654/what-happens-to-the-old-stack-heap-and-initialized-and-uninitialized-data-se)

Comment: @zwol: That's really bad advice. While `posix_spawn` might lack functionality you want (you can solve this via an intermediary helper program, written in C or inline-on-cmdline shell script), any attempt to achieve what you want with `vfork` invokes dangerous undefined behavior. The specification for `vfork` does not allow calling random functions to setup the state for the child to inherit before `execve`, and attempts to do so may corrupt the parent's state.

Comment: @Joshua: A modern implementation of `posix_spawn` performs roughly the same as `vfork` under most conditions. The ones where there's a difference tend to be exactly the cases where `vfork` is highly unsafe: where there are signal handlers installed that `posix_spawn` has to suppress from running in the child before exec.

Comment: @R.. You may recall that we have already had this argument at least once, elsewhere; I would prefer not to rehash it here. It remains my position that `posix_spawn` is not the correct choice under any circumstances, _whether or not_ it is safe to use `vfork` for those circumstances.  Better one should stick to `fork`.

Comment: @zwol: Very well, and I'm happy not to continue into arguing over it if you'd rather not. But I do think it's worthwhile to have both positions presented here for readers to evaluate and make an informed decision.

Comment: @StephenKitt "“This causes the program that is currently being run by the calling process to be replaced with a new program, with newly initialized stack, heap, and (initialized and uninitialized) data segments.” means that the new process is separate from its parent." Does execve() also allocate a new code segment?

Comment: And posix_spawn just failed the very first problem I fed it. "Close all handles not mentioned" because I'm a library spawning processes from multiple threads.

Comment: @Joshua: You could, if you wanted, make a file actions object closing all in-range file descriptors; however, "closeall" type operations are explicitly UB per POSIX, and are incorrect to do. The only correct approach is using `O_CLOEXEC` (or, as library code, assuming your caller does) and blaming somebody else's bad code if fd's leak.

Comment: @zwol I didn’t intend my answer to be read as a recommendation to use `posix_spawn()`; all I was saying that even in POSIX, `vfork()` was removed and that its replacement (in circumstances where `vfork()` is appropriate) is `posix_spawn()`. I’ve added a paragraph to say that `fork()` is preferable for ordinary mortals anyway.

Comment: @Tim yes, it allocates a new code segment.

Comment: Just since it seems that people don't get it right: `posix_spawn()` does not allow you to do arbitrary things while preparing the new process, while `vfork()` permits you to do anything you like if you do it right. Doing it right means that you need to keep a copy of the process state (from the data you like to change)  on the stack of the function that calls `vfork()` from the time before calling `vfork()` and you need to restore this after the parent returns from `vfork()`. Doing this is not more complex than what you need to do with `posix_spawn()`.

Comment: @schily, well the (old) POSIX definition doesn't really give a warm and safe feeling about doing arbitrary things. [It literally says that you can't call anything but `_exit()` and `exec*()`, or modify anything but a single `pid_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/vfork.html). Even if some OS gives more lenient guarantees, with that standard definition, it's not really surprising if people would rather avoid it.

Comment: I would look at highly portable code like `ksh93` and the recent `Bourne Shell` or `csh`. None of these programs uses `posix_spawn()` but rather use `vfork()`. Do you have an idea why these programs use `vfork` when `posix_spawn` is much better?

Comment: @R..: There's an inherent race condition in O_CLOEXEC because two processes could enter posix_spawn at once and inherit each other's handles.

Comment: @ilkkachu: That was always just terrible spec writing. You always could declare and use new variables inside the if block and call functions documented as safe for signal handlers. The two valid implementations are shared memory and equivalent to fork.

Comment: @Joshua, yeah, I don't know if there would have been some other, less restricting baseline functionality that the standard could have documented. Sure, I suppose you can use it properly, _if_ you know the low-level internals (in that particular OS and compiler) well enough to not do anything that would mess things up in the parent. Just needing to think about that can be a bit of a mental roadblock though. Though in a sense I suppose it's "just" a bit like multithreading with some differences.

Comment: @ilkkachu: There are exactly two implementations. Either you have shared memory or it's forwarded to `fork()`. That's easy to reason about if you don't try something dumb like calling `malloc()`. They could have documented it that way. There's a few edge cases they didn't want to bother with like don't try to read from a terminal.

Comment: @Joshua, yes, easy enough if you know what parts of the address space the parent doesn't need, so you can use it in the child. Not having any signal handlers modify the global state from the child might also be useful. But why a restriction on reading from the terminal? Shouldn't that work like any system call, too?

Comment: @ilkkachu: read from a terminal can deadlock if you've changed your pgid or sid already.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `vfork()`, a new process is created and that new process borrows the process image of the parent process with the exception of the stack. The child process is given an own new stack star however does not allow to `return` from the function that called `vfork()`.

While the child is running, the parent process is blocked, as the child borrowed the address space of the parent.

Regardless of what you do, everything that just accesses the stack modifies only the private stack of the child. If you however modify global data, this modifies the common data and thus also affects the parent.

Things that modify global data are e.g.:

- calling malloc() or free()
- using stdio
- modifying signal settings
- modifying variables that are not local to the function that called `vfork()`.
- ...

Once you call `_exit()` (important, never call `exit()`), the child is terminated and control is given back to the parent.

If you call any function from the `exec*()` family, a new address space is created with new program code, new data and a part of the stack from the parent (see below). Once this is ready, the child no longer borrows the address space from the child, but uses an own address space.

The control is given back to the parent, as it's address space is no longer in use by another process.

Important: On Linux, there is no real `vfork()` implementation. Linux rather implements `vfork()` based on the Copy on Write `fork()` concept introduced by SunOS-4.0 in 1988. In order to make users believe that they use `vfork()`, Linux just sets up shared data and suspends the parent while the child did not call `_exit()` or one of the `exec*()` functions.

Linux therefore does not benefit from the fact that a real `vfork()` does not need to set up an address space description for the child in the kernel. This results in a `vfork()` that is not faster than `fork()`. On systems that implement a real `vfork()`, it is typically 3x faster than `fork()` and affects the performance of shells that use `vfork()` - `ksh93`, the recent `Bourne Shell` and `csh`.

The reason why you should never call `exit()` from the `vfork()`ed child is that `exit()` flushes stdio in case there is unflushed data from the time before calling `vfork()`. This could cause strange results.

BTW: `posix_spawn()` is implemented on top of `vfork()`, so `vfork()` is not going to be removed from the OS. It has been mentioned that Linux does not use `vfork()` for `posix_spawn()`.

For the the stack, there is few documentation, here is what the Solaris man page says:

```
 The vfork() and vforkx() functions can normally be used  the
 same  way  as  fork() and forkx(), respectively. The calling
 procedure, however, should not return while running  in  the
 child's  context,  since the eventual return from vfork() or
 vforkx() in the parent would be to a  stack  frame  that  no
 longer  exists.
```

So the implementation may do whatever it likes. The Solaris implementation uses shared memory for the stack frame of the function calling `vfork()`. No implementation grants access to older parts of the stack from the parent.

Comment: Neither the GNU C library nor the musl C library implements `posix_spawn()` on top of Linux `vfork()`.  They both implement it on top of `__clone()`.

Comment: Well, UNIX platforms like Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, *BSD, ... have a real vfork() and implement posix_spawn() on top of vfork(). So it seems that Linux is an exception.

Comment: A private stack sounds great, but BSD doesn't appear to document one. "The vfork() system call can normally be used just like fork(2).  It does
     not work, however, to return while running in the child's context from
     the procedure that called vfork() since the eventual return from vfork() [i.e. in the parent]
     would then return to a no longer existent stack frame."

Comment: @JdeBP: You know `vfork()` just calls `clone()` right? It's literally a one-liner in kernel.

Comment: You are right, there is no private stack. I corrected the text.

Comment: Also Linux literally takes a reference count on the mm, using the same flag as a new thread does. I don't see what you're suggesting as the 3x faster alternative. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/kernel/fork.c

Comment: "Important: On Linux, there is no real vfork() implementation." <-- This is not true and has not been true for at least a decade.  If your shell benchmark is not observing any performance difference between `vfork` and `fork` on Linux, it is doing something wrong.

Comment: (You may have gotten confused because, on Linux, both `vfork` and `fork` are special cases of `clone`.  This is no different from how `open` is a special case of `openat`.  glibc's implementation of `posix_spawn` uses `clone` instead of `vfork` so that it can arrange to run the code that runs in between `vfork` and `exec` on a separate stack, which makes it safe to do all the things that `posix_spawn` can be directed to do in there; but it is still performing a `vfork` _operation_.)

Comment: @Joshua: While it's true that at the syscall level they're roughly equivalent, the function signatures are very different, and this is what matters. In particular `vfork` returning twice is a big part of the problem with it. The possibility of signal handlers running while address space is shared is also a big problem not solved by using `clone` alone; it requires a dance of signal masking, disposition change, and unmasking that's not legal under the contract of the `vfork` function.

Comment: The second half of this answer beginning with "Important: On Linux, there is no real vfork() implementation" is mostly or entirely wrong.

Comment: Please do not make claims without verifying. The current Bourne Shell can be compiled with and without vfork support, so even if you believe that the debugging features from Linux are unable to give reliable results, you could compare the execution times for a configure call with and with vfork in the shell. I use a configure script with 800 tests. On Solaris, the Bourne Shell using vfork needs 30% less system cpu time in total compared to the fork case. On Linux, the same test results in less than 10% less system cpu time. On Solaris it is not 3x as there are many compiler calls included.

Comment: I'd be curious about it if Solaris is beating Linux in absolute terms :-P.  (Dunno if security against Spectre & Meltdown would be significant in measuring).

Comment: Sorry, I currently don't have an installation on the same HW, so I cannot compare. What I can do is this: There is a 12 year old opteron with Solaris where my Reed Solomon benchmark results in exactly half the speed compared to a 2 year old Laptop with Linux. On that Linux system, the total wall clock time is 28 seconds and on the old Solaris system, it takes 44 seconds (vfork) and 53 seconds (fork). The expected Linux wall clock time would be 22 seconds, but is 28 for both fork/vfork cases. Linux seems to give the same performance as you get on Solaris with fork

Comment: There's an unreproducable microbenchmark result showing that Linux and FreeBSD have similar scaling trends to each other [here](https://blog.famzah.net/tag/fork-vfork-performance/). People absolutely mess around with calling vfork() on large Linux processes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731531/faster-forking-of-large-processes-on-linux And it's consistent with the kernel code I linked.  I don't know why your practical examples behave how they do. IMO the burden of proof is on you, if you believe Linux kernel managed to screw up vfork() at some point :).

Comment: You did not yet verify your claims. As long as you cannot give reliable benchmarks that prove otherwise, we need to follow my benchmark results. The pointer you give just contains a smalltalk but no repeatable test similiar to what I presented. My Boure Shell based benchmark is easy to repeat by anone who is interested.

Comment: @schily: What the shell does is irrelevant to whether `vfork` behaves like `fork`, which it doesn't; this is trivial to check at the source level without running performance tests on random applications.

Comment: You may like to repeat the test yourself... get `schilytools` and compile it. Copy the compiled shell to /tmp and then chdir to `sh`and call: `smake clean all COPTX=-DNO_VFORK` and copy the second fork only binary to a different name. Now chdir to the directory `autoconf` and call: `CONFIG_SHELL=/tmp/sh /tmp/sh ./configure` then call `rm *cache` and rerun the command with the binary that was compiled without vfork support.

Comment: @schily, From your comment: "On Solaris, the Bourne Shell using vfork needs 30% less system cpu time in total compared to the fork case. On Linux, the same test results in less than 10% less system cpu time." But in the answer you say that Linux has "a vfork() that is not faster than fork()". Isn't this a contradiction? Which one is it?

Comment: I said that the `vfork` on Linux does not give the performance win I expect, so Linux cannot have a `vfork` implementation that really just borrows the address space description from the parent. Note that SunOS-4.0 introduced a Copy on Write `fork()` call that made `fork` much faster than before since the address space from the parent no longer needs to be copied, but a new address space description still needs to be set up for a COW `fork`. Linux copied this COW idea, so if Linux does not copy the address space description for `vfork` it should give similar performance win as Solaris.

Comment: @schily, no, you wrote in the answer _"This results in a vfork() that is not faster than fork()."_. Go re-read that sentence, it doesn't say anything about a significant performance win, or even anything about what you expect personally. And actually, your answer also gives the opposite impression of the relationship between those two. You say there, as the first thing "On Linux, there is no real vfork() implementation.". That sounds like a statement of fact, not something that you came up with through deduction from the performance difference.

Comment: @schily, I don't care if you want to complain about how some OS is different from another, but right now, it seems you're being misleading or confusing on purpose.